# Defining minimal permissions for a server role to access all databases in MS SQL Server 2012 instance

Tags: sql-server-2012

I have multiple (~15) databases on my local MS SQL Server 2012 instance. I am running FluentMigrator to execute migration scripts on (potentially) all of these databases. Currently I am using Windows authentication to connect to SQL Server with my own Windows Domain account. Corresponding SQL Server login is a member of 'sysadmin' server role, so it has implicit access to all databases and I don't need to create users in each database and map them to this login.

Obviously this setup will not be accepted in production scenario. Whoever will be running FluentMigrator in production is going to have SQL Server login permissions restricted, and certainly will not be a 'sysadmin'. I was trying to define permissions for a dedicated migrator SQL Server login (MigrationAdmin) in as clean and minimal way as possible, so my first thoughts were to create a user-defined server role, grant `ALTER ANY DATABASE` permission to it (which I believe should suffice to execute migration scripts), and make MigrationAdmin a member of this role:

```
CREATE SERVER ROLE udsr_migrator
GO

GRANT ALTER ANY DATABASE TO udsr_migrator
GO

ALTER SERVER ROLE udsr_migrator ADD MEMBER [MigrationAdmin]
GO
```

However, when I run FluentMigrator under MigrationAdmin account, it throws the following exception:

```
!!! System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Cannot open database "databasemigration" requested by the login. The login failed.
Login failed for user 'MigrationAdmin'.
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
```

It appears that, despite `ALTER ANY DATABASE` permission, this login still cannot access this particular database.

Now, I could have mapped MigrationAdmin login to a database user in each database and grant appropriate database permissions to these users. However, I'd really like to avoid descending to the database level and polluting databases with these dedicated users.

So my question is: would it be possible to set up all required permissions on the server level? And if yes, what other permissions must be granted to the above server role, so that a member of this role is able to view and alter all databases in this server instance?

Comment: You would have thought that it would be ALTER ANY DATABASE and VIEW ANY DEFINITION, but i can't get this working either